# Apache Maven 3.1.0 not running

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am running following commands

C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Maven 3.1.0\bin>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Maven 3.1.0\bin>set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;

C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Maven 3.1.0\bin>mvn
**Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Maven 3.1.0\bin>

Let me know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Problem description is unclear. Need more information.

Comment: Have you set MAVEN_HOME environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try running

`mvn -v`

This should list the state of the environment variables Maven depends on.

If any don't match what you've set open a new command prompt for them to take affect.

Putting maven on your path wouldn't be a bad idea as well so you don't have to go to the maven directory whenever you want to run it.